# "Survivors clinging to a raft." Is this sentence right?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english

> "Survivors clinging to a raft."

There is no verb in this sentence.

I know this sentence is not the present progressive/present continuous.

But can this sentence be used independently?

I found this sentence here.
[Definition of cling verb from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cling?q=cling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a sentence. It is a noun phrase - the head is the noun "survivors", and it is post-modified by a participial clause "clinging to a raft".

It can be used independent in the same way that any noun phrase can be used independent, eg in answer to a question:

> What does this picture show? Survivors clinging to a raft.

But it does not narrate anything: it identifies or describes something, viz. the survivors. It has no tense.

Comment: thank you very much.I have other questions.“clinging” is gerund or present participle in this sentence.

Comment: It's a participle (that's why I referred to it as a "participial clause").